# showing that the sequence $\frac{2\sqrt{2n-1}}{n}$ converges to $0$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I'm currently trying to prove that the sequence $\frac{2\sqrt{2n-1}}{n}$ converges to $0$, or that $\left|\frac{2\sqrt{2n-1}}{n}-0\right|<\varepsilon$. Since $\frac{1}{n}\leq\left|\frac{2\sqrt{2n-1}}{n}\right|$, I cannot simply evoke the Archimedean property and prove it this way. I tried doing some algebraic manipulations like multiplying by $\frac{\sqrt{2n-1}}{\sqrt{2n-1}}$, but that yields $\left|\frac{4n-2}{n\sqrt{2n-1}}\right|$, which isnt particularly helpful. Any suggestions?

Comment: Write it as $2\sqrt{\frac{2}{n}-\frac{1}{n^2}}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$0<\frac{2\sqrt{2n-1}}{n}<\frac{2\sqrt{2n}}{n}=\frac{2\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{n}}\to 0$$